# Spring MVC + JUnit failed to load applicactionConnext

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit

Yeasterday i was working at my project, and averything was OK. But today I can't run my Unit test... Yeasterday it was good - in git nothing is changes. Application Works correctly...
I had tried run my test with Dispatcher servlet and bean configuration, but it still has no effect.

**I've got that test class:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = RootConfig.class)
public class QuoteRepositoryImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private QuoteRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertNotNull(repository);
    }
}
```

**And here is stacktrace:**

```
2018-03-19 21:34:27 WARN  GenericApplicationContext:557 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    2018-03-19 21:34:27 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:510 - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1efee8e7: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,rootConfig,aspectConfig,datasourceConfig,securityConfig,userDetailsServiceImpl,aspectTimeCountLogic,communityController,historyController,learnController,loginController,notesController,profileController,registrationController,schedulerController,settingsController,statisticsController,welcomeController,nanoParserImpl,timerTaskImpl,passwordEncoderHelperClass,registrationProcess,notesRepositoryImpl,quoteRepositoryImpl,systemUserMetaDataRepositoryImpl,systemUserRepositoryImpl,systemUserRepositoryInfoVerificatorImpl,systemUserStatsRepositoryImpl,tasksToDoRepositoryImpl,basicDataHandler,temporatySystemUserObjectContainer,webApplicationServletConfiguration,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration,requestMappingHandlerMapping,mvcPathMatcher,mvcUrlPathHelper,mvcContentNegotiationManager,viewControllerHandlerMapping,beanNameHandlerMapping,resourceHandlerMapping,mvcResourceUrlProvider,defaultServletHandlerMapping,requestMappingHandlerAdapter,mvcConversionService,mvcValidator,mvcUriComponentsContributor,httpRequestHandlerAdapter,simpleControllerHandlerAdapter,handlerExceptionResolver,mvcViewResolver,mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector,iTemplateResolver,iTemplateEngine,viewResolver,messageSource,multipartResolver,characterEncodingFilter,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,dataSource,jdbcTemplate,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration,objectPostProcessor,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration,authenticationManagerBuilder,enableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer,initializeUserDetailsBeanManagerConfigurer,initializeAuthenticationProviderBeanManagerConfigurer,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration,delegatingApplicationListener,webSecurityExpressionHandler,springSecurityFilterChain,privilegeEvaluator,autowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration,requestDataValueProcessor,passwordEncoder]; root of factory hierarchy
    2018-03-19 21:34:27 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:566 - Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'mvcResourceUrlProvider': [requestMappingHandlerMapping]
    2018-03-19 21:34:27 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:566 - Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'objectPostProcessor': [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration, securityConfig]
    2018-03-19 21:34:27 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:566 - Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': [securityConfig]
    2018-03-19 21:34:27 DEBUG DisposableBeanAdapter:246 - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'objectPostProcessor'
    2018-03-19 21:34:27 ERROR TestContextManager:246 - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@5b87ed94] to prepare test instance [org.smartlearning.repositories.implementations.QuoteRepositoryImplTest@48503868]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:107)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
        ... 41 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:485)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$41a6cb45.CGLIB$resourceHandlerMapping$30(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$41a6cb45$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$88e812fa.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$41a6cb45.resourceHandlerMapping(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... 42 more
```

Thank You! Please help ;(

Comment: Please close this... and sorry. I just set @ComponentScan in aspect configuration without base packages. Now it's running.

Comment: You can always post your own answer if you think this might be useful to other people who get the same error message. Or if not you should be able to delete the question yourself rather than wait for us to close it.